# get method hierarchy through static code analyser tools

Tags: static-analysis, static-code-analysis

One of our project, we are trying to find all the leaf method call for a method programmatically. I notice that jdt internal provides to get all the method hierarchy. But those jars not available. Using static code analysis tools, can we get method hierarchy ? or can we get any useful this static code analyser tool for my requirement .  Please help me to get this requirement implementation.

Thanks,
Narasaiah

Answer (score 1):

You can try JArchitect (https://www.jarchitect.com).
It could give you all the methods called by another one.